# Websites still detecting VPN/proxy even after I uninstalled VPN apps

Tags: 7.0-nougat, vpn, proxy

4 months ago I used VPN on my Android 7.0 mobile like OpenTunnel, SocksIP. Now, I've uninstalled the VPN, but when I use certain websites, they said VPN/proxy detected and I can't sign up there.

One more thing I want to share is that the VPN proxy detecting issue is just on my Zong SIM. When I use the internet on Jazz SIM, then I don't face this issue.

Someone guide me as to how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache, website storage data and cookies? Alternatively test a different web browser app.

Comment: Ye I did both methods. Clear cookies and change browser. Still have same issue. Kindly solve this.

Comment: If you only encounter the issue on one SIM, then consider contacting them about this. This means that one of the IPs provided by them is considered a VPN proxy (whether it's really a VPN proxy might be irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

When you install proxy/vpn apps they create a vpn on phone
if you delete the app, vpn may still be there until you remove it manually

From Settings>

- Select Connections or Wireless & Networks
- Scroll down to More Connection
- Settings Select VPN
- Tap on the blue settings cog next to the VPN name
- Select Delete VPN profile

and you should be good to go!